# JSP programmatically render

Tags: jsp, servlets, rendering

I need to programmatically render JSP page. As far as I understand, JSP should have some compiler. The question is can I use this compiler dirrectly without JspServlet and others? All I need is documentation how to use JSP compiler (Jasper, for example).

Some additional information would clarify situation, I think. I can not use standard JspServlet. I want to change source JSP before compilation in some way (merge two JSP together to be precise), so I need a way to compile JSP result from InputStream (or Reader) using the JSP compiler directly.

Merging of two JSP is layout requirement. You can ask: "But why this guy just doesn't use SiteMesh or something like this?". One of JSP pages is not static. It's provided by user and stored in database. We sanitify and validates this JSP layout (users are able to use only subset of tags, and all of them are not standart but created specially for them), cache them and so on. But now we need a way to use these JSP pages (which are stored in memory) as layouts for all JSP pages that user request.

Comment: I had a similar problem and the "easiest" solution I found was switching whole project to Velocity (or other template engine) where such tasks are trivial. Looks like you are already too far in the development to make such changes, but just saying...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the server's deploy folder is writable and the server is configured to hotpublish any changes in deploy folder (Tomcat by default does), then you could just let a servlet write JSP files right there and forward the request to some main JSP file.

Imagine that you want to dynamically create a `main.jsp` with this contents:

```
<jsp:include page="${page1}" />
<jsp:include page="${page2}" />
```

Where `${page1}` resolves to `page1.jsp` and `${page2}` resolves to `page2.jsp`, then here's an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org):

```
package com.stackoverflow.q1719254;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/test")
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        File root = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("/"));
        
        String main = "<jsp:include page=\"${page1}\" /><jsp:include page=\"${page2}\" />";
        write(main, new File(root, "main.jsp"));
        
        String page1 = "<p>We are in ${data1}";
        write(page1, new File(root, "page1.jsp"));
        request.setAttribute("page1", "page1.jsp");
        request.setAttribute("data1", "first jsp");
        
        String page2 = "<p>We are in ${data2}";
        write(page2, new File(root, "page2.jsp"));
        request.setAttribute("page2", "page2.jsp");
        request.setAttribute("data2", "second jsp");

        request.getRequestDispatcher("main.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
    
    private static void write(String content, File file) throws IOException {
        try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), "UTF-8"))) {
            writer.write(content);
        }
    }
    
}
```

Execute it at http://localhost:8080/playground/test (or whatever host/contextname you're using) and you'll see

```
We are in first jsp
We are in second jsp
```

To make it more efficient I would cache every resource and make use of `File#exists()` to check if the particular page is already saved on disk.

Comment: Ok, let's dive into requirements. Merging of two JSP is layout requirement. You can ask: "But why this guy just doesn't use SiteMesh or something like this?". One of JSP pages are not static. It's provided by user and stored in database. We sanitify and validates this JSP layout (users are able to use only subset of tags, and all of them are not standart but created specially for them), cache them and so on. But now we need a way to use these JSP pages (which are store is in memory by the way) as layouts for all JSP pages that user request.

Comment: Ok, it will work. But I want my JSP to look a bit more clean. Like <m:page title="Page title">...</m:page> and childs of page tag describe page. Page tag by itself replaces with layout on compilation time. Is this possible in some way?

Comment: Just include taglibs at top of JSP content. Just code JSP the usual way. All you need to do is to store it in webapp's webcontent. See the SSCCE which I've added last.

Comment: Would the sample code work if the either page1.jsp or page2.jsp was modified after the appserver is started? In most production environments, the appservers do not recompile these files.

Comment: That requires then a different approach. Give it another filename and so on. I however don't think that this applies on his specific case.

Comment: @BalusC: over and above the call of duty!!

Answer (score 5):

I'm not totally sure if this is what you are looking for but the [DWR framework](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html) contains a method called `WebContext.forwardToString` that forwards the current request plus a fake response object to a URL and then reads the contents of the buffer into memory.  Here's a sample of the code:

```
StringWriter sout = new StringWriter();
StringBuffer buffer = sout.getBuffer();

HttpServletResponse realResponse = getHttpServletResponse();
HttpServletResponse fakeResponse = new SwallowingHttpServletResponse(realResponse, sout, realResponse.getCharacterEncoding());

HttpServletRequest realRequest = getHttpServletRequest();
realRequest.setAttribute(WebContext.ATTRIBUTE_DWR, Boolean.TRUE);

getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(realRequest, fakeResponse);

return buffer.toString();
```

You could use this to get the results of the jsp rednering and store them in memory.  You can download the source from the above link to see how SwallowingHttpServletResponse works.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use [Tomcat's JspC ant task](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/jasper/JspC.html)?

Comment: Not exactly. I need to compile JSP on server side by myself. So ant task is not what I looking for. But I will look source code of this task. Maybe it will be helpfull. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

JSTL is just a library of tags used inside JSP files. So it really doesn't matter in this context.

Since a JSP compiler transforms JSP files into Java Servlets, I doubt you can have it directly run(a compiler doesn't actually run anything!) or render for that matter a JSP file.

It's actually quite hard to understand from your question what you're really looking for.

Edit: I would recommend jsp:include for the job

Comment: Yes, mention for JSTL is inconcvenient in this context, agree.

And you right, JSP pages becomes servlets after compilation. What I need, is a way to compile JSP pages to the servlets by myself. I can explain my task a little bit deeper. I need to merge two JSP files on some way (from sources) and then compile result.

Comment: Isn't it enough to include one of the JSP files in the other? See jsp:include and <%@include%>

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The rules for JSP merging are non trivial. Of cource this is problem by it self, but...

Answer (score 1):

If the JSP has already been precompiled by the appserver then you could look for the generated .class file . In Tomcat this should be under the $CONTEXT_ROOT/org/apache/jsp/ directory. You might be able to run this class somehow and generate your output.

EDIT: Missed your edit about modifying the JSP source.

Take a look at org.apache.jasper.compiler.AntCompiler (included in jasper.jar in Tomcat). There is a protected method called generateClass which you might be able to override and mess around with :)

Answer (score 1):

Which reason you have to do that? 
If you need merge 2 jsp file to process, maybe using **include**
Or you need other ideas? Can you give sample about your request?