# Programmatically invoke the JSP parser

Tags: java, parsing, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

I would like to invoke the JSP parser programmatically. That means that I want to be able, in Java, to 'run' a jsp page and get its output, without sending it back to the client (I actually want to save the output to a file). I don't want to 'forward' the request to the JSP page. I want to be able to do that on several JSP pages in a row.

What is the best way of doing this?

I have found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719254/jsp-programmatically-render), but BalusC doesn't really answer the question directly.

In case you are wondering, I need to do this is because I want to 'precompile' the JSPs for using on other platforms than a Java servlet container.

EDIT

What I need is not the .class file, but the HTML output. Indeed, that will be static once generated but I have some custom jsp tags and I want to leverage the JSP parser to expand them.

Comment: The reference to another question lost its link.  What is the referenced question?

Comment: updated with the correct reference to the question

Comment: I do wish the JSP and JSTL "template engine" could be programmatically called like other template engines allow. Sigh. I just want to merge data into HTML in order to generate emails. Is that so odd?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I understand the point of all this.

JSPs are parsed and precompiled to `.class` files.  They're Java servlets at that point.  You need a servlet engine to execute them.

If your intent is to capture the generated HTTP response as the "precompiled" response, it would suggest that there's no dynamic content and the response is the same every time you send that particular request.  If that's the case, what you've got is static HTML.

If I'm correct, this would seem to be a poor way to generate such a thing.

If your wish is to precompile JSPs to .class files, the problem is that different Java EE app servers use different JSP precompilation engines.  You can't precompile JSPs using Tomcat and use them on WebLogic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would have static HTML, but I want to be able to parse (pre-compile) the JSPs with several timez with different parameters, hence getting several different possible html outputs. I know this is not the way JSPs are to be used, in a way all I am doing is leveraging the JSP parser's support for custom tags and things such as includes.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get the html output from a jsp page is to actually deploy it to a real webserver and then call the page and save the rendered output.

If you want to automate some part of this, you might want to look into using a testing tool that exercises through the real interface, such as [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) or that emulates the browser, such as [HttpUnit](http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/).

But this is doing much more than just invoking the JSP compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it would be more practical to use template engines like http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/ or http://velocity.apache.org/

Freemarker even seems to support JSP Taglibs: http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/features.html

Answer (score 0):

Is your JSP dynamically generated. If so then you are stepping into a potential disadvantage situation wherein your JSP will be compiled again and again, leading to performance issues.

However if you could have a single large JSP with all the rules that you need to prepare your display, you could use HttpClient to make a call to your own JSP and that would return the HTML. This would ensure that you are not app-server dependent. If you use JSP Parser you are going to be vendor dependent.

But if your JSP is being dynamically constructed then you should look at options wherein your HTML can be generated on Java side. But if it involved rule based HTML creation, you are better off creating it in Java. You can use Apache Jakarta ECS library for this.

And yes JSPs are not meant for this purpose.