# Using freemarker to generate html to send within an e-mail, is their anyway to use a rendered jsp page instead?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, freemarker

The e-mail is being sent using Spring and java mail sender.

Is their anyway I can use a normal jsp view and jstl tags - I don't want to learn another bunch of tags/syntax ?

Currently my code looks like this :

```
StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
Configuration configuration = freeMarkerConfigurer.getConfiguration();
String templateName = "vslEmail.ftl";
Map<String, String> templateVars = new HashMap<String, String>();
templateVars.put("firstName", "john");
templateVars.put("surname", "doe");
try {
  content.append(FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString(configuration.getTemplate(ftlName), tempalteVars));
}
catch (Exception e) {
  // handle
}
// content.append("<br>Test data");
sendMime(defaultEmailAddress, subject, content.toString());
```

I would just prefer to reference a jsp instead of the ftl ?

Comment: The question is not so clear? What do you want: "I can use a normal jsp view and jstl tag...?"

Comment: @Ralph instead of being dependent on ftl I want to use jsp with jstl tags. JSP gets converted to html - I want to use that converted html in my e-mail. Instead of relying on ftl files. I refer to jsps files as views, from mvc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicite render a jsp, but you need a Request Object!

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/mai/myMail.jsp").include(request, response);
```

See also this [StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1719549/280244) (and the other answers to that question). It shows an example to create a (fake) response object, that allows you to process the created html.

Comment: would you regards this is as sensible ? using freemarker, although seemingly a popular tool, does not appeal to me.

Comment: @NimChimpsky: Sorry I do not understand your comment (I am from germany and my english it not as good as the one of an native speeker).

Comment: Well, a major point of FreeMarker is that unlike JSP, it doesn't require Servlet environment, so you can generate e-mails and such without having a Request object. But if you mix in JSP... then all that was thrown out of the window. And the JSP integration was never without complications...

Comment: That is correct: But jsp Tags and jsp Syntax are strongly tied to its execution environment. I can not imagine to use jsp-tags and syntax outside of this environment. On the other hand, you should may have a look at some jsp (tag) testing frameworks/libs, I think they have to solve this problem somehow. -- But to be honest, learning a new mark-up language is not so hard.

Answer (score 1):

You could always fire off a request to a JSP sitting on your own web server, slurp up the response, and drop it into your email.  It's a little hacky, and care must be taken to make sure you don't open up those pages to the outside world, but it would work.

Comment: yeah, there is nothign built into spring to make it easy/conventional then ?

Comment: not that i'm aware of, but there's a lot of stuff buried in spring that i'm not familiar with!